# How to write this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I hope someone can help me out here :)

We have to sets :
STUDENTS » All the students of the school
CLASSES » All the classes of the school
And the relation :
STUDENTSCLASSES » Relates the students to the classes they attend to

We need to write the set that includes only the students who attend to the "Maths class".

Would it be something like this? : $\{student STUDENTSCLASSES class | class = Maths\}$

Or rather : $\{(student,class) \in STUDENTS X CLASSES | class = Maths\}$

Or what is not ?

I think my answers are wrong since the answer we are looking for is a set of elements, where the elements are just students..

Thanks !

Comment: Why the votes to close? This is a perfectly legitimate question with perfectly legitimate demonstrated effort!

Comment: @amWhy closure operations are always nice and appealing

Comment: Thank you all for your help ! It's hard to choose only one answer, so let's say I choose randomly.. thanks again guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, we have the set $S$: the set of all students, and $C$: the set of all classes. We want to denote the relation $A \subset S\times C$ as the set of ordered pairs $(s, m) \equiv s\;\text{ STUDENTCLASSES }\;m$, meaning student $s\in S$ is in a maths class $m\in C$. $$A = \{(s, m)\mid s\in S, m\in C, s\text{ STUDENTCLASSES } m\}$$

Now, if you want to denote just the set of students taking math classes, then indeed, you want $$\{s\mid (s \text{ STUDENTCLASSES } m) \land (s\in S) \land (m \in C)\} \\ \\= \{s\mid (s, m)\in A\}$$

Comment: But how sould I write "s is in m" ?
Thanks !

Comment: @Rod you would write it as $sRm$ or $(s,m) \in R$

Comment: @Rod I tried to clarify: we can simply use the given relation "STUDENTCLASSES" which is already defined such that "a STUDENTCLASSES b" means "student a is in class b." Here, we limit the set A of all ordered pairs (student, maths class) as defined in my post.

Comment: OK. The commas between s \in S , m \in C , sSTUDENTCLASSESm would be ANDs  ??

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can use $\land$ if you prefer. Typically, commas in "set builder" notation $p, q, r$ mean $p\land q\land r$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Why your answer begins with {(s,m)|.... and the answer by @Mauro-ALLEGRANZA under begins with {s|....

That's what I don't get. Am I looking for a subset ? The content is just elements that are students.. beacuse in your answer we would obtain a subset containing pairs, right ? Thank you so much !

Comment: If you want just the set of students taking math classes, then indeed, you want $\{s\mid (s \text{ STUDENTCLASSES } m) \land (s\in S) \land (m \in C)\} = \{s\mid (s, m) \land (s\in S) \land (m \in C)\}$.

Comment: Okay, yes that what we are looking for. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot here !

Comment: @amWhy hungry lions don't get any chicks! ;-)

Comment: @Dror Yes, you're right! ;-)

Comment: @Rod - "Why your answer begins with ... and the answer by Mauro ALLEGRANZA begins with ..." ? But what is $ <s,m> \in STUDENTCLASSES$? simply : $s \in STUDENT$ and $y \in CLASSES$, exactly what amWhy has written ...

Comment: Thank you all for your help ! It's hard to choose only one answer, so let's say I choose randomly.. thanks again guys !

Answer (score 0):

If the student set is $S$, class set is $C$, and the relation "Student $s$ attends class $c$" as $R$, where$R \subseteq S \times C$:
$$\{\text{all students who attend math class}\}=\{s\mid sRmath\}=\{s\mid(s,math) \in R\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$STUDENTS$ is the set of students, so that $x \in STUDENTS$ means "$x$ is a student".

$CLASSES$ is the set of classes, so that $y \in CLASSES$ means "$y$ is a class".

$STUDENTCLASSES$ is the relation between students and classes, so that $x STUDENTCLASSES  y$ means "the student $x$ attend the class $y$".

We have that :

> $STUDENTCLASSES = \{ <s,y> : s \in STUDENT \land y \in CLASSES \}$

where $\land$ is the logical *connective* "and".

Math class is an element of the set $CLASSES$: call it $m$. We have that $m \in CLASSES$.

The set of students that attend Math class is

> $X = \{ s : <s,m> \in STUDENTCLASSES \}$

**NOTE** I assume that you are familiar with the concept of *ordered pair* (in symbol : $<x,y>$).

Comment: Thanks ! I'm between this answer and @amWhy's .. trying to figure out the different between both options.. Thank you very much. Rod

Comment: @Rod - You are welcome. There are no basic difference : he/she used more symbols and less words; I suppose, due to your question, that you are a "beginner" in logic and set theory...

Comment: Yes, actually the teacher explained the topic in one class and we have to submit the assignment tomorrow.. ! Thanks :) This really helped.

Comment: Good luck! Please, check that the teacher has already explained the concept of *ordered pair* or *ordered couple* ...

Comment: Yes, she did ! Thanks

Comment: Thank you all for your help ! It's hard to choose only one answer, so let's say I choose randomly.. thanks again guys !

Comment: @Rod - you are welcome ! Choose the answer you understand better, i.e. the one you are able to explain to your class colleagues.